# EXCEPTION with IIS 7.5 with Webservice built on .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

i have webservice that is using .net 2.0 server 2003 32 bit
when i host it under iis 6 with basic and intergated auth enabled it works great.
but when i host the same service under IIS 7.5  server 2008 64bitwith intergated app pool running with apppool identity with basic and windwos auth enabled. i have 32bit support enabled on the app pool 
i get follwoing error below

> ```
>   <soap:Body>
>       <soap:Fault>
>          <soap:Code>
>             <soap:Value>soap:MustUnderstand</soap:Value>
>          </soap:Code>
>          <soap:Reason>
>             <soap:Text
> ```
>
> xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: SOAP
>   header Security was not understood.
>          at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderHandling.SetHeaderMembers(SoapHeaderCollection
>   headers, Object target, SoapHeaderMapping[] mappings,
>   SoapHeaderDirection direction, Boolean client)
>          at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
>          at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

Comment: Do you have a reference to a certificate thumbprint in your configuration file? I've found that IIS 7.5 requires upper-case thumbprints with no spaces, and will fail to read thumbprints that are OK for previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't have all the software installed to run the code? Like WSE 3?

Or is it a default web service you are running?

Cerveser